# jQuery if statement triggered twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, readonly

I'm attempting to write a read only values in a html input using jQuery, and I've run into a problem where a single if statement fires twice.

Basically the input starts with a default value in the html [this is the readonly value]:

```
<input id="main-field" type="text" value="dan" >
```

Then, a jQuery 'keypress keydown' function checks the index of the pressed key in relation to the readonly word and if the index is before or after the word it returns 'true' which will add the characters, otherwise it will return false which will prevent adding chars. The problem is that if I type before the word it increases the index of the readonly word twice, where it should be increased by one (since the readonly word has moved by one index for each char).
Here's the 'keypress keydown' function; hopefully it's easy to understand (let me know if not, I want to get better at that as well):

```
var readOnlyEnd = $('#main-field').val().length,
    readOnlyStart = 1;

$('#main-field').on('keypress keydown', function(event) {

    var character = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();

    // note: using the jquery caret plugin
    var pos = $('#main-field').caret();

    // handling new character between 'a' and 'z' and the delete char.
    if (((character >= 'a') && (character <= 'z')) || (event.which == 8)) {

        // if delete is pressed:
        if (event.which == 8) {
            if (pos == readOnlyEnd) return false;
            else if (pos < readOnlyStart) {
                if (pos == 0) return true;
                if (pos > 0) {
                    console.log('reudce index!!');
                    // Will reduce indexes.
                    readOnlyStart -= 1;
                    readOnlyEnd -= 1;
                    return true; // Will delete.
                }
            }
            else if ((pos >= readOnlyStart) && (pos < readOnlyEnd)) return false;
        }

        // within the word.
        else if ((pos >= readOnlyStart) && (pos < readOnlyEnd)) return false;

        // before the readonly word. - HERE IS THE PROBLEM, INCREASING TWICE.
        else if (pos < readOnlyStart) { 
            readOnlyStart += 1;
            readOnlyEnd += 1;
            return true; // Will add character
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else { 
        // In case something that doesn't affect the input was pressed (like left/right arrows).
        return true;
    }
});
```

Note: I'm using the jQuery caret plugin for the cursor place.

Please let me know if you have any ideas or suggestions, or if the solution to my problem is similar to a solution to another problem on here

Comment: many if statement is there which if statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use only one event. Either `keypress` or `keydown` in following statement:

```
$('#main-field').on('keypress keydown', function(event) {
```

This will fire event twice on a single key press.

So, change your statement to:

```
$('#main-field').on('keypress', function(event) {
```

Comment: Yes! thank you :)
By the way the 'keypress' only does not work but when I change it to 'keydown' only it perfectly does!